# Overlaping shadow div on another

Tags: css

I have 3 DIVs, first is the navigation, second is SHADOW of navigation and third is content, I want the SHADOW div to overlay/overlap on cotnent DIV, may be it will be done with z-index ? or position:fixed ? I tried so many things and now am lost, please check this and please help..

http://jsfiddle.net/3nqay/

```
 <div style="height:50px;background:green">this is navigation</div>
 <div id="shadow" style="height:30px; background: red url(IMAGE_PATH)"></div>
 <div id="content" style="background:blue; height:150px"> this main main content</div>
```

PS : after trying so many things, I removed all styles, this is the basic structure

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but if you want to move the shadow up and keep it in flow of the document just add margin-top:-5px; to the shadow div

```
 <div style="height:50px;background:green">this is navigation</div>
 <div id="shadow" style="margin-top:-5px; height:30px; background: red url(IMAGE_PATH)"></div>
 <div id="content" style="background:blue; height:150px"> this main main content</div>
```

Edit: If that's not right I have provided you a link to JSFiddle in hope that helps you.

http://jsfiddle.net/3nqay/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is a CSS issue more than anything, I would suggest reading up on CSS positions and Z-index.

http://jsfiddle.net/3nqay/2/

CSS:

```
#nav {
height:50px; 
background:green; 
position:relative;}

#shadow, #content {
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;}

#shadow {
height:30px; 
backround:red; 
z-index:10;}

#content {
background:blue;  
height:150px;}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav"> this is navigation </div>
<div style="position:relative">
<div id="content"> this main main content</div>
<div id="shadow">this is shadow</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add following CSS.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
#shadow {
    position:absolute;
    width: 100%; /* or your specific width in px */
}
```

or try

```
#shadow {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    margin-top: -30px; /* Equal to #shadow height */
    padding-top: 30px; /* Equal to #shadow height */
}
```

Note: If you add `position:relative` or `position:absolute` to #content, in that case, you have to use `z-index`.